# Can I select a previous sibling in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to select #btnsrchicon parent's child #txtSearch. I tried in the below format, but not works

**HTML**

```
<div id="topSearch">

<input id="txtSearch" name="search" type="text" value="" id="txtSearch" onClick="ClearTextBox()" onkeypress="searchenter(event);"/>
<button id="btnsrchicon" class="submit" onClick="search_another();"></button>

</div>
```

and CSS

```
<style>
 #txtSearch{display:none;}
#btnsrchicon:hover < #topSearch+#txtSearch
{
 display: block;
 border:2px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It's not possible :(

Comment: Do you mean previous sibling selector? Your button element doesn't have any children element.

Comment: Yes, previous sibling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't offer this solution.

What you can do is a javascript solution when user hover elem:

```
$('#btnsrchicon').prev('#txtSearch').addClass('yourClass')
```

Something like that:

```js
$('#btnsrchicon').hover(function(){
  $(this).prev('#txtSearch').addClass('show');
}, function(){
  $(this).prev('#txtSearch').removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
#txtSearch{
  display:none;
}

#txtSearch.show {
 display: block;
 border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="topSearch">
  <input id="txtSearch" name="search" type="text" value="" id="txtSearch" onClick="ClearTextBox()" onkeypress="searchenter(event);"/>
  <button id="btnsrchicon" class="submit" onClick="search_another();">Button</button>
</div>
```

Edit: Another solution

```css
#txtSearch{
  display:none;
}

#btnsrchicon:hover + #txtSearch
{
 display: block;
 border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="topSearch">

<button id="btnsrchicon" class="submit" onClick="search_another();">Button</button>
<input id="txtSearch" name="search" type="text" value="" id="txtSearch" onClick="ClearTextBox()" onkeypress="searchenter(event);"/>

</div>
```

... and you adjust the position with CSS.

Comment: Oh sad; I am trying in CSS

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi You can position your button before and use a selector. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi edited

Comment: Good thinking; But the text box should display first, before button

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi Use css to change order

Comment: Use position absolute per example

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent selector in CSS. But you can select a following sibling. A possible solution might be to change the order of the `button` and the `input` and use the `+` selector, like that:

```css
#btnsrchicon:hover + #txtSearch {
  display: block;
}

#txtSearch {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnsrchicon" class="submit" onClick="search_another();">Bouton</button>
<input id="txtSearch" name="search" type="text" value="" id="txtSearch" onClick="ClearTextBox()" onkeypress="searchenter(event);"/>
```

Then, if the order is really important, you can use some css to visually revert the order

Comment: Good thinking; But the text box should display first, before button

Comment: You can use css to visually change the order (flexbox with row-reverse or column-reverse, absolute positioning, ...)